# asp.net mvc error not showing ysod

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

Im running an asp.net mvc site on iis7, using iis express in dev and when an exception occurs in one of my views, the browser returns something that looks like binary in a text editor.

Its not generating the normal ysod.

Has anyone seen this before?

Cheers,
Byron

**EDIT**

Its related to my compression action filter. It looks like the response isnt 'decompressing' if an exception occurs in the view.

```
public class EnableCompression : ActionFilterAttribute {

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {

        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;

        acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP")) {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        } else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE")) {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  Stepping through your code, or at least setting a break point at the beginning of the code where you think is causing this?

Comment: Hey, im not after the actual exception, im wondering why when an exception is throw when rendering a view template its not showing me the traditional yellow screen

Answer (score 0):

it is because you aren't handling all/default cases for request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"].  You have an "if/else if"  with no other handling for other cases.  See all possible values in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html.  Then add a default handler for requests not caught by your if/else if.  Also, you may want to use .ToLower and test agains only lowercase values.